# adding clickable zones to an svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

[png representation of svg circlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj24P.png)

So I've got this circlet, and I want to make the text clickable (3 distinct clickable areas).  Is going through raphael.js or d3.js the only way to achieve this?  Is something like this normally very time-consuming?  I'm not even sure how many hours to budget if I wanted to have someone else do this on upwork.  Mostly, I'd like to learn how to do it though.

Comment: Just add the links :)

`<svg width="100" height="100"><a href="https://www.example.com"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"></circle></a></svg>`

Comment: Nope, that won't do it.  I have three different words in the svg, and I want them all to be clickable separately, and the rest of the circlet should not be clickable.   I'm looking for a more in-depth solution.

Comment: Wrap each text element in its own link. Play with it. You'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `d3` would be something like:

```
d3
  .select("svg#svgId")
  .selectAll("text")
  .classed("cursor-pointer", true)
  .on("click", function(){
    var txt = d3.event.target.textContent;;
    var redirectUrl = false;
    switch(txt) {
      case "DESIGNERS:
        redirectUrl = "https://www.example.com";
        break;
      // ... so on
    }
    if (redirectUrl !== false){
      window.location.href = redirectUrl;
    }
  });
```

in css rules:

```
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;  
}
```

**Check out this example:**

```js
d3
  .select("svg#mySVG")
  .selectAll("text")
  .classed("cursor-pointer", true)
  .on("click", function() {
    var txt = d3.event.target.textContent;
    alert("Redirect to: " + txt);
  });
```

```css
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="40" viewBox="0 0 500 40">

  <text x="0" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35">
    Hello,
  </text>
  <text x="100" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35">
    out there
  </text>
</svg>
```